# Rename table name with Doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I've searched pretty much everywhere but I wasn't able to find anything.

Is there a command or a procedure to change the name of a table (so inside doctrine annotation) without loosing data?

Basically, something that will produce something like

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE old_table RENAME new_table;
```

MySQL commands taken from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rename-table.html)

Should I write manually the migration file with `doctrine:migrations:generate`?

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: @StoryTeller MySQL, but I suppose that should exist a "universal" method

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Change table name for given entity.

   ```
   /** @Entity @Table(name="new_table_name") */
   class MyEntity { ... }
   ```
2. Generate a new migration.
3. Erase contents of `up()` and `down()` methods and replace them with custom SQL (`ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...`).

Keep in mind that migration generator is meant as utility/semi-automatic tool.

Comment: Yes, so, basically, I can reach the same by running `php app/console doctrine:migrations:generate` (that, indeed, is what I've done 'till now)

Comment: This doesn't handle updating foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best possible way is to use a two-step / two-migration approach. With the 1st migration rename the table only, and with the 2nd migration take care of the renaming parts, e.g. FKs.

The steps I took:

1. Rename the PHP entity, lets say `App\Entity\OldName` to `App\Entity\NewName`
2. Create a new migration, e.g. `symfony console make:migration`
3. Replace the `up()` with `ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME new_name;` and `down()` with `ALTER TABLE new_name RENAME old_name;`. In other words, this migration only renames the table itself, **without** FKs, indexes, etc.
4. Run the migration, e.g. `symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n`
5. Again, create a new migration `symfony console make:migration`. The generated code for this migration handles all the FKs, columns rename (if you did any in the PHP entity), indexes, etc.
6. Run this migration too, e.g. `symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n`